# Grunt + Rails just for test javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen many posts in stackoverflow about Grunt + Rails, but many cases asked about changes from Grunt.js to Rails asset pipeline, that is not my case.

My Gruntfile was set up to work with Mocha, in other words, just for test javascript codes.

So my doubt is: How the best way to organize my files into rails project?

I thought about creating a directory in my test path called "javascript" and put all test into there, after change options in Gruntfile.

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had some Jasmine specs in our recent rails project. You could follow Jasmine's convention:

```
project root/
    spec/
        javascript/
```

Since another JavaScript testing framework has already done what you are suggesting, creating a "javascript" folder in your "test" folder would work just fine.